# Query a table using SQL to show data in a VERY specific order

Tags: sql, excel, adodb

I have a rather simple question on Excel/SQL that is driving me nuts...

I have a simple table in Excel, located on Sheet "DataBase"/Range A1:C2500 (it is dynamically set depending on row number):

```
 A   |     B      |  C
ID   |    Date    | Price
--------------------------
1    | 01/01/20xx | 11
2    | 01/01/20xx | 12
3    | 01/01/20xx | 13
4    | 01/01/20xx | 14
5    | 01/01/20xx | 15
    ...
1500 | 01/01/20xx | 11500
```

In another Sheet named "Report" I have a report that needs to display the Prices in a very specific ID order, which is specified in the left column ("A") (with occasionally placed blank/empty rows).

```
 A   |   B
ID   | Price
------------
10   | 

15   | 

300  | 


23   | 
20   | 
    ...
```

I have successfully filled the "B" column by using the following SQL string with an ADODB connection (I know this could be **very** easily done with other methods but I'm implementing SQL because I pretend to Query an Access table in the future, rather from Excel itself):

```
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

With cn
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & "" _
    & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;"""
    .Open
End With

sql_string=
"SELECT [DataBase$A1:C2500].Price 
FROM [Report$A1:A30] LEFT JOIN [DataBase$A1:C2500] ON [Report$A1:A30].ID =[DataBase$A1:C2500].ID 
WHERE ((([DataBase$A1:C2500].Data)=#01/01/20xx# OR ([DataBase$A1:C2500].Data) is null);"

Set rs = cn.Execute(sql_string)

Sheets("Report").Range("B2").CopyFromRecordset rs
rs.close
```

It works fine when I have a maximum of ~700 rows/IDs in Report.Column(A) and all prices come in the right/expected rows.

If I have like 1000 or more rows/IDs, the query will group all "blank" values on top of the table and the rest of the data comes below the blank rows...

So, to my questions:
1) Why is that happening? would it be easy to correct or
2) Is there a better way to pull data from excel/access in a very specific order and with random empty rows inbetween using SQL?

Comment: To return a SQL result-set in a specific order, you will need to use the [ORDER BY Keyword](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp) at the end of your Select statement.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but, the ORDER BY would work fine when doing simple sorting stuff, like ascending, descending or even use a CASE along with it....but I would have to cover all possibilities inside the CASE statement and it is not practical and hard to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after some digging....I've come to a solution. Don't know if it is the most efficient (I noticed some lag when compared to what I had before) but it sure works.

It works by creating a table called "TempTable" with ID and Price data filtered by Date. Then it is Left Joined with the table containing the IDs in the order I need with as many blank rows as necessary.

Here it is:

```
SELECT TempTable.Price
FROM [Report$A1:A30] 
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT [DataBase$A1:C2500].ID, [DataBase$A1:C2500].Price 
     FROM [DataBase$A1:C2500] 
     WHERE  (([DataBase$A1:C2500].Data)=#01/01/20xx#))  
     AS TempTable 
ON [Report$A1:A30].ID=TempTable.ID;
```

Hope it helps in case someone comes accross the same problem!

Tks!